# Uploading videos using trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io

I'm considering using trigger.io to build an app which can upload videos. As videos can become quite large and also timeconsuming to upload on low bandwith connection, I'm unsure if trigger.io will be able to handle this.

1. I would expect to be able to cache the video on the phone. Are there any limitations regarding size? Where would the files be stored?
2. Is there any built in way to upload the video in chunks? Ideally I would like to have this running in background process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videos captured with [file.getVideo](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/file.html#file.getVideo) are indeed saved on the device - they are in the gallery, and can be accessed at a later time with the `source: "gallery"` option.

We are limited by the device's own storage, obviously, but don't impose limits beyond that.

We do do file uploads in the background - although exactly how this behaves is somewhat platform dependent, so you should make sure your targeted platforms work as you wish.

For chunked uploads, do you mean split the file into sections, to be combined on the server manually? Or do you mean a lower-level resumable upload capability? We don't support this at the moment, but we'd be open to implementing something in the future!